# JSON data not include entity

Tags: mysql, json, spring, hibernate, rest

I am developing a restful api.I have two entities. User and UserRole. When i send the request to api for user, it gives me

```
{
    "id": 11,
    "name": "mert",
    "username": "zbrave",
    "password": "$2a$10$N0eqNiuikWCy9ETQ1rdau.XEELcyEO7kukkfoiNISk/9F7gw6eB0W",
    "email": "asd",
    "photo": "",
    "enabled": true,
    "roles": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "role": "ADMIN"
        }
    ],
    "online": false
}
```

When i send the request for UserRole, it returns

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "role": "ADMIN"
    }
]
```

But in UserRole entity, there is a User entity. JSON not return User entity.

```
public class UserRole implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;
    ...
    }



public class User implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = UserRole.class, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<UserRole> roles;
    ..
    }
```

I can get the user roles from user entity's json. But not the reverse. Is there any wrong things ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using  @JsonBackReference/ @JsonManagedReference so yeah that is the expected behavior , the side in the jsonBackReference wont be serialized, this is actually necessary to avoid infinite recursion since jackson will keep serializing each side of the relation from its reference in the other side, that is why you need to skip serializing one side

There is a nice solution to this, its mentioned in this [link](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/bidirectional-relationship-in-json) , the idea is to generate a reference to the parent entity, so if you are serializing user, you will have user->role->[reference to user instead of user], all you need to do is to annotate your entities with @JsonIdentityInfo

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class UserRole implements Serializable {


@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class User implements Serializable {
```

so just do this and remove  @JsonBackReference/ @JsonManagedReference

Comment: I use these two annotations for recursion. Your approach is solved the problem. But the json conclude just reference ids. Is there any different solution ? I already give id from database, why i give other id ?

Comment: @zBrave this is the available solution for now , if you want to be able to serialize both sides  you can also use DTO, this is a different id, its used to reference  the parent object o break the recursion